# Awk regex for a string of exact length that ends in ":"

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I just can't get the regex right:

```
awk '$6 ~ /:${14}/ {print $6}' file
```

I need to print out the 6th field if it's 15 characters long and ends with a ":".

Here's an example: `oAFKq7XS001224:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `--posix` as:

```
awk --posix '{ if ($6 ~ /^.{14}:$/) print $6}' file
```

[**Command in action**](http://www.ideone.com/JI1RG)

From `awk` manual page:

> Interval expressions are only
>   available if either **--posix** or
>   **--re-interval** is specified on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
awk '$6 ~ /^.{14}:$/ { print $6 } ' file
```

Comment: yep, that's it, just needs the --posix switch.